# how can I show my ID Name Age in c++ OOP

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

*Hello, I just started c++ OOP. i can't show my ID NAME AGE please help me I try to find the problem but I can't.I cout  name id age when it run it show like that Hello my Name is : My age is : 0 My ID is : 4354512
thank you before.*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class person
 {
  public:
   string name;
   int age;
   int id;
   void set_name( string myname)
    {
     myname = name;
    }
   void set_age( int myage)
   {
    myage = age;
   }
  void set_id( int myid)
  {
    myid = id;
  }
};
class student : public person
 {
  public:
   void display()
   {
    cout<<"Hello my Name is : "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"My age is : "<<age<<endl;
    cout<<"My ID is : "<<id<<endl;
   }
 };
int main()
 {
  student obj;
  obj.set_name("NuthVireak");
  obj.set_age(19);
  obj.set_id(004);
  obj.display();
  getch();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setters are reversed:

```
void set_name( string myname)
{
    // you are setting the local parameter myname
    // to the member name which is probably defaulted to zero
    // myname = name;
    // try
    name = myname;
}
void set_age( int myage)
{
    // same here
    // myage = age;
    age = myage;
}
void set_id( int myid)
{
    // same here
    // myid = id;
    id = myid;
}
```

Comment: thank you StaticBeagle. now Name,Age,ID are displayed.

Answer (score -1):

```
void set_name( string myname)
{
 this->name = myname;
}



void set_age( int myage)
   {
    this->age = myage;
   }

void set_id( int myid)
  {
    this->id = myid;
  }
```

Comment: when I used this I got 2 Error:|17|error: request for member 'age' in '(person*)this', which is of pointer type 'person*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
|21|error: request for member 'id' in '(person*)this', which is of pointer type 'person*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

Comment: after you edit "." to "->" now it's worked thank for helping me.